# Problema en Asignacion del command a instancias de Button tkinter mediante un for

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Tengo cuatro clases, 
    KeyboardButtons
    Display
    Render
    Keyboard

Cuando instancio KeyboardButtons el objeto tiene un  atributo buttons, que es una lista con botones creados a partir de una tupla de strings que sera usados para ser asignados como el text de los nuevos botones.

la clase Display instancia un obejto de la clase Entry, que sera usado para mostrar el text del boton oprimido.

Cuando se instancia la clase Render esta recibe como parametro del constructor el display y en ella (La clase Render) esta declarado el metodo render_it(to_render)

En la clase Keyboard se unen el Keyboard al Display mediante un Objeto render, en ella mediante mediante el metodo  bind_keyboard_to_display(self) se une el keyboard al display usando instanciando un objeto render y asignado a cada boton una lambda que llama al metodo render_it del objeto render previamente instanciado.

Mi problema es que al correr el codigo, todos los botenes escriben un unico caracater en el display, que es el ultimo de la de la tupla que se uso para crear los botones.

Mis clases:

KeyboardButtons

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
#-*-coding: utf-*-
from tkinter import *

class KeyboardButtons(object):
    #Default Values to a calculator keyboard tuple
    cal_keyboard_values = (
        '7', '8', '9', '^', '/',
        '4', '5', '6', '%', '*',
        '1', '2', '3', 'c', '-',
        '0', '00', '.', '=', '+'
    )

    def __init__(self,root, keyboard_values = None):
        self.root = root
        self.buttons = []

        if keyboard_values == None:
            self.keyboard_values = KeyboardButtons.cal_keyboard_values
        else:
            self.keyboard_values = keyboard_values

        self.button_creation()

    def button_creation(self):
        for i in self.keyboard_values:
            self.buttons.append(Button(self.root, text = i, width = 2))
```

Keyboard

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
#-*-coding: utf-*-
from tkinter import *
from KeyboardButtons import *
from Render import *

class Keyboard(object):
    def __init__(self, root, display, chars_source_buttons = None):
        self.root = root
        self.keyboard_frame = Frame(self.root)
        self.keyboard_frame.grid(column = 0, row = 1)
        self.chars_source_buttons = chars_source_buttons
        self.current_buttons = KeyboardButtons(self.keyboard_frame, self.chars_source_buttons)
        self.display = display

        self.bind_keyboard_to_display()
        self.buttons_possition()

    def buttons_possition(self):
        _row = 0
        _column = 0
        for button in self.current_buttons.buttons:
            button.grid(row = _row, column = _column)
            _column += 1
            if _column == 5:
                _row += 1
                _column = 0

    def bind_keyboard_to_display(self):
        render = Render(self.display)
        for button in self.current_buttons.buttons:
            value = button.cget('text')
            button.config(command = lambda : render.render_it(value))
```

Render

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
#-*-coding: utf-*-

class Render(object):

    def __init__(self, display):
        self.display = display


    def render_it(self, to_render):
        self.to_render = to_render
        self.display.set(self.display.get() + self.to_render)
```

Display
    #!/usr/bin/python3

```
#-*-coding: utf-*-
from tkinter import *


class Display(object):
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.display_content = StringVar()
        self.display = Entry(self.root, textvariable = self.display_content)

        self.display.grid(column = 0, row = 0)
```

Comment: Ya que has puesto casi todo el código, podrías también poner el "main" que falta para poder probar a ejecutarlo y ver exactamente qué ocurre?

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en este bucle:

```
def bind_keyboard_to_display(self):
    render = Render(self.display)
    for button in self.current_buttons.buttons:
        value = button.cget('text')
        button.config(command = lambda: render.render_it(value))
```

y proviene de que la variable `value` que le pasas a cada una de las `lambda` es la misma. Vale que su valor va cambiando en cada iteración del bucle, pero eso no es evaluado en la asgnación `command = lambda`. Al final todas las `lambda` que asignas tienen el mismo código que es `render.render_it(value)`, siendo `value` la referencia a esa variable, y no el valor que tenga en el momento de definir la lambda.

Cuando pulsas un botón de la interfaz, se ejecutará su correspondiente `lambda` y *en ese momento* se mirará el valor de `value`. Para entonces el valor de esa variable es `+` (el último que tomó en el bucle). Por eso todos los botones insertan el mismo valor.

La forma de evitarlo es crear una variable local en la `lambda` que tome el valor de `value`, y usar ese valor local en `render_it()`. Así:

```
def bind_keyboard_to_display(self):
    render = Render(self.display)
    for button in self.current_buttons.buttons:
        value = button.cget('text')
        button.config(command = lambda v=value: render.render_it(v))
```

En este caso, la asignación `v=value` tiene lugar en cada iteración del bucle, por lo que `v` será una variable diferente en cada iteración (y con un valor diferente). Así pues, esto ya funcionaría correctamente.