# ¿Cómo bindear la misma tecla a diferentes funciones en tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

estoy haciendo un programa de búsqueda y no sé como hacer para que un click dependiendo del label sobre el que esté haga ejecute diferentes funciones. De momento este es el código que tengo: itera sobre la lista de resultados, crea el label y bindea un click a una función utilizando el valor i o v.get() (es lo mismo) como argumento de esa función. Lo que el código hace actualmente es ejecutar la función con un único argumento sin importar donde haga click y no sé cómo arreglarlo. Muchas gracias

```
for i in resultados_lista:
        v=tk.StringVar()
        resultado_label =tk.Label(tab1, textvariable=v)
        v.set(i)
        f = font.Font(resultado_label, resultado_label.cget("font"))
        f.configure(underline=True)
        resultado_label.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)
        resultado_label.configure(font=f)
        resultado_label.bind("<Button-1>",lambda e: abrir_resultado(i))
```

Comment: Un caso casi igual estaba respondido [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/252633/7123)

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en el alcance de la variable de iteración. La manera de solucionarlo es mediante la declaración de una variable dentro de la propia definición de lambda y asignándole a esta el valor de la variable de iteración:

```
resultado_label.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e,i=i: abrir_resultado(i) )
```

Añadiendo la linea que te muestro debería solucionar el problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya me funciona bien